# C return if characters are the same

Tags: c

So, I'm just learning how to code in C and I'm a bit stumped by what my teacher is asking. Basically, we need to create a program that reads characters from two separate files character by character and if the two characters are the exact same it is to be printed to a third file. Normally, I would use an array to do this but, we have specifically been told that we are not allowed to use an array. I sort of have it working in that it prints characters to the third file but it prints numbers and punctuation in addition to characters. Obviously, I'm missing something but I don't know what it is. Here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fp, *fp2, *ofp;
    char a, b;
    fp = fopen("input1a.txt", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("input1b.txt", "r");
    ofp = fopen("output.txt", "w");
        while((a=getc(fp))!= -1){ 
            b=getc(fp2);
            if(isalpha(a) == isalpha(b)){
               putc(a, ofp);
               letters++;
            }
        }
    return 0;
}
```

From what I have read, isalpha should check to see if the character is an alphabetical character but, in this instance is there something better for me to use? Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: Why does it need to be an alphabetical character at all? Your stated requirement doesn't ask for that.

Comment: Aside, please check the result of `getc(fp2);` for `-1` too and break out of the loop, and better to use `EOF` than `-1`. Moreover `char a, b;` should be `int a, b;` since `getc` returns `int`, and `isalpha` and `putc` also take `int`.

Comment: You're correct in that `isalpha(a)` checks whether `a` is alphabetic. So `(isalpha(a) == isalpha(b))` is true if `a` and `b` are both have the same result for that test. In other words, you'll write to your output if either both `a` and `b` are alphabetic, or if both `a` and `b` are not alphabetic, and whether they match or not.

Comment: Note: `getc` returns an `int`, not a `char` intentionally. For most implementations,  you cannot represent all possible values in a `char`. Read the man-page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the problem

```
if(isalpha(a) == isalpha(b)) {
```

it sould be

```
if (isalpha(a) && isalpha(b) && a == b)
```

You are not comparing whether the characters are equal, but instead you are comparing if both are alphabetic or not, in case they are both alphabetic or they are both *NOT* alphabetic the character will be printed to the file.

Also, get used to writing safe code which is also clean and readable, like the following (*note that there are elegant methods to handle errors, and you can add error messages*):

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    FILE *in[2];
    FILE *out;
    int chars[2]; // getc() returns `int' not `char'
    int counter;

    in[0] = fopen("input1a.txt", "r");
    if (in[0] == NULL)
        return -1;
    in[1] = fopen("input1b.txt", "r");
    if (in[1] == NULL) {
        fclose(in[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    output = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    if (output == NULL) {
        fclose(in[0]);
        fclose(in[1]);            
        return -1;
    }

    counter = 0;
    while (((chars[0] = getc(in[0])) != EOF) && ((chars[1] = getc(in[1])) != EOF) { 
        if (chars[0] == chars[1] && isalpha(chars[0])) {
           putc(chars[0], out);
           counter++;
        }
    }
    // Release ALL resources, it's a good habit
    fclose(inputs[0]);
    fclose(inputs[1]);
    fclose(output);
    // Not required but a good habit too
    return 0;
}
```

Don't use *magic* numbers, `EOF` is normally -1 but it's better to use `EOF` to make the code readable and robust.

Comment: Can be shortened as `(a==b && isalpha(a))`

Comment: Why not `fclose(output)` as well as in[0] and in[1] before exiting main?